# Eloquent (Laravel) query in many to many relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have many to many relation(Eloquent Laravel) and i want to filter item by tags.

```
Table_Item        Table_Item_Tag       Table_Tag
ID  Name       ID  Item_id  Tag_id       Id  Name
1  Item A       1    1        1          1   Tag A
2  Item B       2    1        2          2   Tag B
                3    2        1
```

Filter result should be like this: `

```
Filter: Name:Tag A&B : Sum of Item 1
        Name:Tag A :   Sum of Item 1
```

Any ideas on how the query should look like? Ive been struggling to get the sum of items who have both tags

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking here, you might want to expand into a bit more detail.

Comment: @JamesFlight Imagine if you have the option of adding tags to clients. I want to filter clients who have TagA, clients who have TagB, and clients who have both TagA and TagB. The result should be the sum of clients that have TagA, sum of clients who have TagB, and sum of clients who have both TagA and TagB

Comment: What do you mean by the 'sum' of the clients? A collection/array of clients that have the tag?

Comment: @JamesFlight yes exactly, an array of clients that have a specific tag. or the array of clients that have both tags

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Eloquent relations are set up properly, you will want something along these lines:

```
$tags = ['Tag A', 'Tag B']; // Or get from input or wherever

Item::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $q = $q->where('name', $tag);
    }
})->get();
```